# php4 to php5 migration

Tags: php, php4, php-5.2

We got project, its migration site from php4 to php5,

What are the thing first i should do,

In which parts i should concentrate,

Is there any procedure ,

Give top high 15 point for php4 to php5 migration,

Guess client using the Informix , ut not sure, may be Mysql also,

Comment: What is the goal that client is trying to achieve with the migration?

Comment: client site is php4 , need to migrate to php5, so asking, step by step, how going to migrate, in genral , we know how migrate to php5, but dont know the document level, so what is the chk list for migrating site from php4 to php5

Comment: What I was asking - is what's the purpose of a migration? It's like I need a car... But which car would widely depend on what do you need it for: transporting 10 children, or racing alone...

Comment: @Serge the purpose could 'only' be to stop using a software (php4) that's not maintained anymore ; that alone would seem like a good reason to migrate to php5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be honest, what you probably need to do is simply study the [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5 FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.migration5.php) and the more detailed [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) section of the PHP manual  - as this will tell you pretty much all you need to know.